# Getting month from today's date as an input in a textfield

Tags: vba

I recorded a script which runs a transaction in SAP.

While creating the selections for the transaction there is a field where I have to give a number for a month. (For example 02 for February 03 for March …)

While recording I set the field value to "02":

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKKA0100-BIS_ABGR_M").text = "02"
```

I want this number to change every month. What I created:

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim month As String = today.Month
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "kkaq"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkKKA0100-WIP0A").selected = true
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKKA0100-BIS_ABGR_M").text = month
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKKA0100-BIS_ABGR_J").text = "2020"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtKKA0100-VERSN").text = "0"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkKKA0100-WIP0A").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[2]").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "J:\80_Applications\SAPGuiScripting\01_TXT_Files\01_TXT_Files\"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "TEST.txt"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
```

This code returns an error.

Comment: try `session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKKA0100-BIS_ABGR_M").text = Format(month,"00")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtKKA0100-BIS_ABGR_M").text = right("0" & month(Date) - 1, 2)
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please:

```
Sub testMonthOfDate()
  Dim today As Date, mnth As String
  today = Date
  mnth = CStr(Format(month(today), "00"))
  Debug.Print mnth
End Sub
```

Then, use it as you need.
It is recommended to avoid using of 'month' as variable (it is VBA reserved). It works, but it can create confusions.

Comment: I didn't test it,  but i'm quite sure it would work